# How to put 2 images top and buttom with only Html

Tags: html

im having troubles on one of my projects. Im trying to put 2 Images but different but it ends up like this.

[The Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th3Bs.png)

[Its not the full image but you can already see whats happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgkPI.jpg)

Please Help. If you need more info just comment back.
Im not that good at CSS so please try making HTML Only. **Reply please**

Comment: Actually, we can't "already see what's happening." You need to explain it to us. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put 2 divs

```
<div><img src="img1.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="img2.jpg" /></div>
```

or use section